Late 60s\early 70s vampire movie that opens with a shovel going through a casket lid
Might have been a Castle production... Beginning of flick, a long shot at dusk of a burial party in the middle of nowhere. (The credits had not come up yet.) As the party prepares to lower the casket, the audience sees a man approaching the gravesite. 
The casket has been lowered, and just as they start to shovel dirt, the man grabs a shovel, goes to the hole, and throws it into the box, piercing the box deeply. The camera shoots down into the hole, through the box lid, to show it is a vampire, screaming from the shovel now sticking in him. The music comes up loudly, and shows the title. For years I have tried to learn the name of the movie.

The Kiss of the Vampire (AKA Kiss of Evil), a Hammer production from 1963.

Gerald (Edward de Souza) and Marianne Harcourt (Jennifer Daniel), are a honeymooning couple in early 20th-century Bavaria who become caught up in a vampire cult led by Dr. Ravna (Noel Willman) and his two children Carl (Barry Warren) and Sabena (Jacquie Wallis).

Here's the pre-credits scene you were looking for (the shovel is used around the 3 minute mark):



